# Audio recording, a tool for human-aided drum quantizing

Tags: audio, plugins, music, recording, beat-detection

I have this situation: the drummer records the track (8 tracks in a multitrack session). Now, how do I check how distant are the recorded beats from their theoretical position i.e.: there is always some error in human recorded tracks, but is there any software that can show me the ideal (theoretical, quantized) beat and the recorded one and could alert me if the error is too big.

P.S.: I'm searching for a standalone tool, or for a plugin that can work with Adobe Audition 3 or Nuendo 3.

Comment: Is it midi(digital drums) or audio(real drums)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to know, copy the track, hard-quantize it and compare the two. If you want to "fix" it rather than just know what to fix, use a "windowed" quantize. This will ignore notes already close enough to the beat but move duff ones. I know Logic and Cakewalk have this, surely it's somewhere in Nuendo?

Answer (score 0):

Would Audacity's "Beat Finder" help?
http://www.mediadefendr.com/sample-packs/ 
http://audacity.sourceforge.net/

Comment: The "beat finder" feature allows you to specify a threshold to reduce false positive results.